# jQuery text search - how do I show a "No results" div when using an if else conditional?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on a "live" text search in the html on a page using jQuery.

The function below works as a "live" search, when a minimum of three characters is entered to start the search.

```
$('#search').keyup(function() {
    var text = $(this).val().trim();
    var minLength = 2;
    $('.record.active').removeClass("active");
    if (!text.length) return;
    if (text.length > minLength)
    $('.record').each(function() {
      if ($(this).text().toLowerCase().includes(text)) {
        $(this).addClass("active");
      }
    });
```

But what I want to do is show "No results" when there are no results. I'm trying to use an if else statement to determine if there are any records with the active class. But function in the snippet below doesn't work; it simply shows "No ResultsNo ResultsNo ResultsNo Results...." with no search results.

```js
 $('#search').keyup(function() {
    var text = $(this).val().trim();
    var minLength = 2;
    $('.record.active').removeClass("active");
    if (!text.length) return;
    if (text.length > minLength)
    $('.record').each(function() {
      if ($(this).text().toLowerCase().includes(text))
        $(this).addClass("active");
        else
        $('.record').not("active");
        $(".no-results").append("No Results");
    
    });
  });
```

```css
.record {
display: none;
}

.record.active {
display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Search <input type='text' id='search' placeholder='Search Text'>

<br />

<div class="no-results"></div>

<br />

<div class="record">Now is the time for all good men to come to the aid of their city</div>
<div class="record">Now is the time for all good women to come to the aid of their country</div>
<div class="record">Now is the time for all droids to come to the aid of their universe</div>
<div class="record">Now is the time for all fluffy bears to come to the aid of their wilderness</div>
<div class="record">Now is the time for all short people to come to the aid of their county</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You should use curly braces around your `if` statements to increase code readability.

To handle the no result case, you could show/hide a `div` depending on the number of records having the `active` class :

```js
$('#search').keyup(function() {
    var text = $(this).val().trim();
    var minLength = 2;
    $('.record.active').removeClass("active");
    if (!text.length) return;
    if (text.length > minLength)
    $('.record').each(function() {
      if ($(this).text().toLowerCase().includes(text)) {
        $(this).addClass("active");
      }
      if($('.record.active').length){
        $(".no-results").hide();
      } else {
        $(".no-results").show();
      }
    });
  });
```

```css
.record {
display: none;
}

.record.active {
display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Search <input type='text' id='search' placeholder='Search Text'>

<br />

<div class="no-results">No results</div>

<br />

<div class="record">Now is the time for all good men to come to the aid of their city</div>
<div class="record">Now is the time for all good women to come to the aid of their country</div>
<div class="record">Now is the time for all droids to come to the aid of their universe</div>
<div class="record">Now is the time for all fluffy bears to come to the aid of their wilderness</div>
<div class="record">Now is the time for all short people to come to the aid of their county</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! That works great. But for some reason, it doesn't work on my localhost; I'll have to dig into that. Do you know how I could do hide() on the no-results div on initial page load? In the snippet, "No results" shows up when you first run the snippet.

Comment: You could update the rule `.record { display: none; }` to `.record, .no-results { display: none; }`.

Comment: Thanks, it looks a little glitch in the function; with no search results, the no-results div is `<div class="no-results" style="">No results</div>` with an empty style, while with search results, it's `<div class="no-results" style="display: none;">No results</div>`. Shouldn't `style=""` be `style="display"block"`? This appears to be why it doesn't work on my localhost, but works in the snippet.

Comment: @BlueDogRanch What does not work ? You should consider asking a new question to explain the new problem you are facing. It might be related to your browser, or it's maybe something else but it's not convenient to ask/answer questions in the comments.